# Empty Firebase recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to do a Firebase Recyclerview in a fragment, but isn't showing any data. This fragment is inside a Navigation Drawer. I already did the recyclerview inside a activity a worked but with fragment no data appears

My fragment class

```
public class fUniversidade extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
final static String DB_URL = "https://vbook-3c75d.firebaseio.com/recycler_data";
EditText nameEditText;
Button saveBtn;
ArrayList<mUniversidade> informations = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerView rv;
ViewAdapter adapter;
Firebase fire;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_universidade, container, false);

    rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.re_uni);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(getContext());
    fire = new Firebase(DB_URL);

    this.refreshData();

    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("Universidade");
}

private void getUpdates(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    informations.clear();
    for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        mUniversidade i = new mUniversidade();
        i.setNome(ds.getValue(mUniversidade.class).getNome());
        informations.add(i);
    }

    if(informations.size()>0){
        adapter = new ViewAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), informations);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Sem dados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}

private void refreshData() {
    fire.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            getUpdates(dataSnapshot);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

And this is my adapter

```
public class ViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>{
Context c;
ArrayList<mUniversidade> information;


public ViewAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<mUniversidade> information) {
    this.c = c;
    this.information = information;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_universidade, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String name = information.get(position).getNome();
    holder.nameTxt.setText(name);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return information.size();
}}
```

Can anyone please tell me where is the mistake?

Comment: Have you defined a ViewHolder? I don't see any in your snippets, I see it now, my bad. Check if you committed the fragment transaction too

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a beginner, can you explain me how to make the fragment transaction. I didn't see this in any tutorial that I watched.

Comment: If you want to really understand the android framework, it's better you learn from books and the documentation (type the class name, select it and press Ctrl+Q in android studio). The video tutorials are usually less informative as compared to the books. Some good books are Reto Meier's Android 4 Application Development and Wei Ming Lee's Beginning Android 4 Application Development. There's one very large book too available which I cant remember the title but you may come across it

Comment: This link may give you several places to learn how to make fragment transactions: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=making+a+fragment+transaction+in+android&atb=v75-3_q&ia=web

Comment: Thank you Cool Guy CG, I solved the fragment transaction problem, but my recyclerview still empty.

Comment: Can I have a look at your viewholder implementation and the XML file used as the layout? Maybe I'm missing some details.

Comment: I put the code here https://gist.github.com/janainasilv/d0bca55ff47c68e95d72af90b18ca864 Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to add more code.